# Find Element Inside Table Row

Tags: jquery, html-table

How with jQuery I can grab the content of this table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Element 1</th>
    <td>Red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Element 2</th>
    <td>Pink</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to find the color of the line `Element 1`. I do not need a `.each` as I want just on color.

---

I tried:

```
var color = find("<th>Element 2</th>").next().("<td>").html();
```

Comment: This is not a proper way to search for elements. You could search by number of child (etc. `:nth()`) or `:last-child`, or even by `:contains(sometext)`.

Comment: Because I do not want to use .each in this case how can I change my code using answer (nth, last-child or contains)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list of elements (that is, your colors), you can't avoid a *loop* or an `.each`. You could for example:

```
$("table tr td:last-child").each(function(k,v) {
   alert( $(v).html() );
});
```

or:

```
var colors = $("table tr td:last-child");
for(var x=0;x<colors.length;x++) {
   alert( $(colors[x]).html() );
}
```

*But this is not a good method*, since your cells cant really get identified (etc. no `id` or `class`). In case of changed table structure, the current javascript could not work. I recommend naming after your retrievable information, like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Element 1</th>
    <td class="color">Red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Element 2</th>
    <td class="color">Pink</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and:

```
$("table tr td.color").each(function(k,v) {
   alert( $(v).html() );
});
```

or:

```
var colors = $("table tr td.color");
for(var x=0;x<colors.length;x++) {
   alert( $(colors[x]).html() );
}
```

**UPDATE**

Just saw you want only the first color. Just use the following:

```
var color = $("table tr:first-child td:last-child").html();
```

If you really want to search by text in `<th>`, check this:

```
var color = $("table tr th:contains('Element 1')").next().html();
```

Comment: I want to find the color of the line Element 1. I do not need a .each as I want just on color.

Comment: No, pls see my update. But note that structure is important in this case, recommended to use some `class` to get after sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
var color=$('th:contains(Element 1)').next().text()
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mhw2m43f/)**

Comment: I want to keep : Element 1 is Red, Element 2 is Pink, ... Why my first code do not work ?

Comment: I want to find the color of the line Element 1. I do not need a .each as I want just on color.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this, I have tested it and working.

```
    <script>
        $().ready(function(e){
            $("table tr td").each(function(e){
                alert($(this).html());
            })
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: because you have used find, you should use something like this $(body).find("table tr td").

Answer (score 0):

```
var color ;
$("table td").each(function(){
color=$(this).html();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to use these values more than once, it's probably best to make an object out of the values. like this:

```
var colors = {};
$('tr').each(function(){
    colors[($('th',this).html())] = $('td',this).html();
});
```

try it out http://jsfiddle.net/asvvd4rh/